# Grouping in SQL Server when you have a datetime2 column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime, group-by

I have a table with the following format:

```
Date                        Login
2020-03-12 01:42:00.0000000 agent2 
2020-03-12 01:42:00.0000000 agent2   
2020-03-12 01:43:00.0000000 pma
2020-03-12 01:43:00.0000000 agent2
2020-03-12 01:43:00.0000000 agent2 
2020-03-12 01:43:00.0000000 agent3  
2020-03-12 01:43:00.0000000 agent1 
2020-03-12 01:43:00.0000000 agent1
```

I need to group it per user per minute, however, when using the group by on the login field (as per below) I am getting an error "Column 'Date' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause".

```
SELECT  Date , Login
  FROM connections
  GROUP BY login
```

Expected result would be something like:

```
Date                        Login    Connections
2020-03-12 01:42:00.0000000 agent2   2
2020-03-12 01:43:00.0000000 pma      1
2020-03-12 01:43:00.0000000 agent2   2
2020-03-12 01:43:00.0000000 agent3   1
2020-03-12 01:43:00.0000000 agent1   2
```

Is this because one cannot group by when you have a datetime2 type column? Do I need to create another table for the connections count?

Comment: *"Can you group by when you have a datetime2 type column?"* Yes, you can group by any expression you want (excluding deprecated data types), being a `datetime2` makes no difference. Show us your attempts, expected results and explain why the attempt isn't what you want.

Comment: That statement will error, there's no aggregation on your column `Date`. It's not inthe `GROUP BY` you said it was,.

Comment: You should probably learn how to use `GROUP BY` properly.  You can't write query whatever you want, and expect SQL Server to understand and run it.

Answer (score 1):

You *aren't* grouping by the `datetime2` column in your query, so of course it isn't working.

You need to add it to the `GROUP BY` and then add a `COUNT`:

```sql
SELECT [Date], --I suggest a better name, date is a different data type
       [Login], --I suggest a different name. LOGIN is a reserved keyword
       COUNT(IDColumn) --I assume you have an ID you can count on?
FROM dbo.connections
GROUP BY [Date],
         [Login];
```